# How do you reverse a list at a given value?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm trying to design a code that will reverse a given list at the index of a given value. The rest of the list beyond the value will be printed in correct order, but I can't seem to complete it.

This is the code I have so far.

```
def reverse(my_list, value):

    lst = []
    lst2 = []

    for x in range(my_list[0], my_list[value]):
        x = my_list[x]
        lst2.append(x)

    for i in range(len(lst2)-1, -1, -1):
        x = lst2[i]
        lst.append(x)

    for x in range(my_list[value], len(my_list)):
        x = my_list[x]
        lst.append(x)

    print(lst)
```

If the input is this.

```
reverse([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 5)
```

The output should be.

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

But instead the output is this.

```
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Can anyone help me to determine how to get the needed output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes in first and third cycles are wrong, you have to iterate through indexes not values. Write like here:

```
def reverse(my_list, value):

    lst = []
    lst2 = []

    for x in range(0, value):
        x = my_list[x]
        lst2.append(x)

    for i in range(len(lst2)-1, -1, -1):
        x = lst2[i]
        lst.append(x)

    for x in range(value, len(my_list)):
        x = my_list[x]
        lst.append(x)

    print(lst)

reverse([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 5)
```

output: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to implement with slicing:

```
def reverse(my_list, value):
    return my_list[:value][::-1] + my_list[value::]
```

Comment: There is no need for double 'slicing' and therefore two temporary lists creation - sure, it won't have much impact on a small list but it will most definitely show both in speed and memory use with large lists and arbitrary slices. `my_list[value-1::-1] + my_list[value:]` will work just as fine with one less list creation.